# How to set a basePath in Ktor similar to Retrofit's `Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl)?

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor-client

I am trying out `Ktor` by converting some existing project that's currently using `Retrofit`.

Although I could easily convert the request into something like:

```
client.get {
    url("$BASE_URL/something/somepage/another")
}
```

It seems very tedious to always add the `$BASE_URL` to all paths every time. In retrofit, we could simply do something like:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .create(SomeServiceClass::class.java)
```

I've triede using `defaultRequest` and setting the `BASE_URL` there but apparently you could only set the `url.host` and not the whole `basePath`.

Is there a way to do the same thing in `Ktor`? or if there is none, what's the best practice to handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From official [docs](https://ktor.io/docs/default-request.html#url)

DefaultRequest allows you to configure a base part of the URL that is merged with a request URL.

```
defaultRequest {
    url("https://ktor.io/docs/")
}
```

If you make the following request using the client with the above configuration, ...

```
val response: HttpResponse = client.get("welcome.html")
```

... the resulting URL will be the following: https://ktor.io/docs/welcome.html

Answer (score 24):

You can!

In order to do so you need to set your default request when you instantiate your client.

```
val httpClient = HttpClient(Android) {
        defaultRequest {
            host = "my.zoo.com"
            url {
                protocol = URLProtocol.HTTPS
            }
        }
    }

val response = httpClient.get<List<CatsResponse>>(
        path = "animals/cats"
)
```

This will call `https://my.zoo.com/animals/cats`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I see. This just confirms that you can't set a base path but could set a base url instead. Can I ask another question about ktor? maybe you could help me out. By any means do you know how to set SSL in Ktor?

Comment: In the default request you can provide anything you would in your request builder `HttpRequestBuilder`. Check out the class to see all the options.

defaultRequest {
                host = "animals.zoo.com"
                url {
                    protocol = URLProtocol.HTTPS //Set scheme to https.
                }
            }